'float' object has no attribute 'isdigit' how do i fix
print("Area calculater")
print("to select use 1 for triangle, 2 for square, 3 for rectangle.")
print("4 for circle, 5 for trapezoid,exit for exit")
while True:
    c=input("enter choice ")
    if c=="exit":
        break
    if c.isdigit()==False:
        print("selection was wrong please re-enter")
    else:
        c=int(c)
        if c==1:
            b=float(input("enter base "))
            h=float(input("enter height "))
            while not b.isdigit() or not h.isdigit():
                print("you entered wrong base or height please re enter")
                b=input("enter base")
                h=input("enter height")
            print(b*h/2)
        elif c==2:
            b=float(input("enter base "))
            while not b.isdigit():
                print("Base was entered wrong please re-enter")
                b=input("enter base")
            print(b*b)
        elif c==3:
            b=float(input("enter base"))
            h=float(input("enter height"))
            while not b.isdigit() or not h.isdigit():
                print("base or height has been entered wrong. please re-enter")
                b=input("enter base")
                h=input("enter height")
            print(h*b)
        elif c==4:
            r=float(input("enter radius"))
            while not r.isdigit():
                print("radius was entered wrong")
                r=input("enter radius")
            print(r**2*3.14)
        elif c==5:
            b=float(input("enter base"))
            b2=float(input("enter base two"))
            h=float(input("enter height"))
            while not h.isdigit() or not b.isdigit() or not b2.isdigit():
                print("The height, base, or second base has been entered wrong")
                b=input("enter base")
                b2=input("enter second base")
                h=input("enter height")
            a=((b+b2)/2*h)
            print(a)
        else:
            print("Invalid choice. Please try again.")
print("thank you. Have a nice day ")

i tried entering 5 but it gave me the error

Why are you testing after conversion? (Also, isdigit is not a "does this string look like a number" test. It looks for digit characters. Inputs like 3.5 and -2 do not pass an isdigit check.)

You're closing the barn door after the horse is gone.  Once you call float on a string, it isn't a string anymore.

If you want to know if user input (a string) can be converted to float, try the conversion and handle ValueError exception

print("Area calculater")
print("to select use 1 for triangle, 2 for square, 3 for rectangle.")
print("4 for circle, 5 for trapezoid,exit for exit")
while True:
    c=input("enter choice ")
    if c=="exit":
        break
    if c.isdigit()==False:
        print("selection was wrong please re-enter")
    else:
        c=int(c)
        if c==1:
            b=input("enter base ")
            h=input("enter height ")
            while not b.isdigit() or not h.isdigit():
                print("you entered wrong base or height please re enter")
                b=input("enter base")
                h=input("enter height")
            b = float(b)
            h = float(h)
            print(b*h/2)
        elif c==2:
            b=input("enter base ")
            while not b.isdigit():
                print("Base was entered wrong please re-enter")
                b=input("enter base")
            b = float(b)
            print(b*b)
        elif c==3:
            b=input("enter base")
            h=input("enter height")
            while not b.isdigit() or not h.isdigit():
                print("base or height has been entered wrong. please re-enter")
                b=input("enter base")
                h=input("enter height")
            b = float(b)
            h = float(h)
            print(h*b)
        elif c==4:
            r=input("enter radius")
            while not r.isdigit():
                print("radius was entered wrong")
                r=input("enter radius")
            r = float(r)
            print(r**2*3.14)
        elif c==5:
            b=input("enter base")
            b2=input("enter base two")
            h=input("enter height")
            while not h.isdigit() or not b.isdigit() or not b2.isdigit():
                print("The height, base, or second base has been entered wrong")
                b=input("enter base")
                b2=input("enter second base")
                h=input("enter height")
            b = float(b)
            b2 = float(b2)
            h = float(h)
            a=((b+b2)/2*h)
            print(a)
        else:
            print("Invalid choice. Please try again.")
print("thank you. Have a nice day ")

Below is the message that I tested:
Area calculater
to select use 1 for triangle, 2 for square, 3 for rectangle.
4 for circle, 5 for trapezoid,exit for exit
enter choice 5
enter base2
enter base two3
enter height4
10.0
enter choice 2
enter base 2
4.0
enter choice 3
enter base2
enter height4
8.0

you can get a string from b = input('something'), but if you use b = float(input('something')), you get a float number. So you got the error.
Please clean the code next time.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
